# `this.props` inside `getDefaultProps()` of React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add a prop that depends on other props that will be basically passed by the component's owner component.

So I did:

```
propTypes: {
  user: React.PropTypes.object,
  comment: React.PropTypes.object
},

getDefaultProps: function() {
  return {
    admire: new Admire({
              user: this.props.user, 
              comment:this.props.comment
            })
  };
}
```

But it seems like props `user` and `comment` are not accessible at `getDefaultProps` call time.

Is there any way to define a default prop that depends on other props that will be passed from owner components?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[getDefaultProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html#declaring-prop-types-and-default-props) is called before any instances are created and thus cannot rely on `this.props`.  It's meant to get the default props in case the owner hasn't passed them.

An alternate solution would be to use `getInitialState` as this would give you access to `this.props.user` and `this.props.comment`.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't really be modifying the props like this, I'm fairly certain you'll get a console warning about doing so.

You may want to store `Admire` into state, via the `getInitialState` function.

E.g.

```
propTypes: {
    user: React.PropTypes.object,
    comment: React.PropTypes.object
},
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        admire: new Admire({
            user: this.props.user,
            comment: this.props.comment
        });
    };
}
```