# Applying logic to defaultProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-proptypes

I have a component which has one required property and one optional property. The optional property acts as an override mechanism which, if not present, defaults to a value derived from the required property. It's set up like this:

```
function fruitColour(fruit) {
  switch (fruit) {
    case 'banana':
      return 'yellow';
  }
}

const Fruit = (props) => {
  const { type } = props;
  let { colour } = props;

  colour = colour || fruitColour(type);

  return <p>A yummy {colour} {type}!</p>
}
```

This allows me to have a mature, ripe banana:

```
<Fruit type='banana' />
```

Or a younger, unripe banana:

```
<Fruit type='banana' colour='green' />
```

The project I'm working on enforces that if a `prop` value isn't read as a constant it must be given a default value within `defaultProps`. Currently I'm doing this:

```
Fruit.defaultProps = {
  colour: ''
}
```

But this is silly because my component's logic already handles the default state.

Am I stuck with this pattern, or is it possible to read the `type` property within `defaultProps` in order to do something like this:

```
Fruit.defaultProps = {
  colour: (props) => fruitColour(props.type)
}
```

...and then read the `colour` property as a constant as well, dropping the defaulting logic?

Comment: Why not just do `const colour = props.colour || fruitColour(type)`

Comment: check this: [this.props inside getDefaultProps() of React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125985/this-props-inside-getdefaultprops-of-react)

Comment: In my opinion, defaultProps is more for security than for real application logic. It should ensure that if people forget props, the component will not crash.  Selecting a fallback value is the responsibility of render. I'm perfectly fine with your actual solution. Using props dependent logic in defaultProps could have some weird behavior. What if you change 'banana' to 'apple' ? I'm pretty sure it will use default props as it is and you will have a yellow apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a stateless component, use destructuring with defaults instead of `defaultProps`. Since the default argument is [evaluated each time the function called](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Evaluated_at_call_time), you can call `fruitColour(fruit)`, and use it's result as the default.

```js
const Fruit = ({ type, color = fruitColour(type) }) => (
  <p>A yummy {color} {type}!</p>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Fruit type="banana" color="red" />
    
    <Fruit type="banana" />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);

function fruitColour(fruit) {
  switch (fruit) {
    case 'banana':
      return 'yellow';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Looks like a much better approach. Thanks!

Comment: It seems the project still manages to complain about the defaulting not being there, and with the defaulting it overrides the destructuring.

Comment: Seems I needed simply to specify `undefined` within the `defaultProps` declaration instead of an empty string. Thanks again!

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - welcome. I never use `defaultProps` for stateless component, and I don't get any errors/warnings from react. Check your linter/ide settings.